# Are there some conditions on a metric space $X$ such that these two types of weak converge of finite signed Borel measures on $X$ are related?

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all finite **signed** Borel measures on $X$, and
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ be the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$.

Then $\mathcal C_b(X)$ is a real Banach space with supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ [is a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440407/the-space-of-finite-signed-measures-with-the-total-variation-norm-is-a-banach-sp). Let $\mathcal M(X)^* := (\mathcal M(X))^*$ be the continuous dual. Let $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$.

- We define the first type of weak convergence by
  $$
  \mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_b(X),
  $$
  Let $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_b(X))$ be the topology induced by $\overset{1}{\rightharpoonup}$.
- We define the second type of weak convergence by
  $$
  \mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \varphi(\mu_n) \to \varphi (\mu) \quad \forall \varphi \in \mathcal M(X)^*,
  $$
  Let $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal M(X)^*)$ be the topology induced by $\overset{2}{\rightharpoonup}$.

Of course, we have $\mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \implies [\mu] \le \liminf_n [\mu_n]$. Also, we can prove [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568256/does-mu-n-overset1-rightharpoonup-mu-necessarily-imply-mu-n-overset) $\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \implies [\mu] \le \liminf_n [\mu_n]$.

> Are there some conditions (locally compact, separable, Polish,...) on $X$ that ensure [$\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \implies \mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$] or [$\mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \implies \mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$]?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568256/does-mu-n-overset1-rightharpoonup-mu-necessarily-imply-mu-n-overset) question on MSE, but it seems to receive no answer. So I post it here.

Comment: For general metric spaces: What are functions vanishing at infinity?

Comment: @DieterKadelka A function $f \in \mathcal C_b (X)$ vanishing at infinity means that for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x:|f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ is compact.

Comment: One direction seems to be simple since $C_0(X) \subset C_b(X) \subset M^*(X)$. We always have that $\mu_n \to^2 \mu$ implies $\mu_n \to^1 \mu$. For the other direction you need strong assumptions, I think. Maybe you find something in the old book of Z. Semadeni, Banach spaces of continuous functions I (1971).

Comment: @DieterKadelka Do you mean by $\mathcal C_b(X) \subset \mathcal M(X)^*$ that there is an isometrically isomorphic embedding from $\mathcal C_b(X)$ to $\mathcal M(X)^*$?

Comment: I find some points here quite confusing: (a) Why do you introduce the spaces $\mathcal{C}_0(X)$ and $\mathcal{C}_b(X)^*$, although they do not appear in the question? (b) Anyway, the space $\mathcal{C}_0(X)$ is quite a red hering unless $X$ is locally compact: it is easy to check that $X$ is locally compact if and only if for every $x \in X$ there exists $f \in \mathcal{C}_0(X)$ such that $f(x) \not= 0$.

Comment: @Akira: Yes, $\mathcal{C}_b(X)$ embeds isometrically into $\mathcal{M}(X)^*$; but you do not even need the isometric property to see that convergence in the sense of (2) implies convergence in the sense of (1): this is simply clear since testing against any function $f \in \mathcal{C}_b(X)$ defines a continuous linear functional on $\mathcal{M}(X)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I have removed unnecessary parts.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you so much! I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example.  $X = [0,1]$ with the usual metric.  $\mathcal C[0,1] = \mathcal C_b[0,1] = \mathcal C_0[0,1]$.  $\mathcal C[0,1]^* = \mathcal M[0,1]$.
Let $\mu_n$ be the unit point-mass at $1/n$ and $\mu$ the unit point-mass at $0$.  Show $\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu $ is true but $\mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ is false.

Whatever "some conditions" to insure $\big[\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \implies \mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu\big]$
are, they are not satisfied by $[0,1]$.

Comment: The space $\mathcal M(X)^*$ is quite hard to imagine. Could you provide a map $\varphi \in \mathcal M(X)^*$ such that $\varphi (\mu_n)$ does not converge to $\varphi (\mu)$?

Comment: @Akira: Let $f$ be any bounded measurable function on $X$. Then $\mu \to \int f~d\mu$ is in $M(X)^*$. Choose $f = 1_{\{0\}}$ f.i.

Comment: The entire space $\mathcal M(X)^*$ is, indeed, hard to imagine.  But there are simple examples (as Dieter showed) of elements of $\mathcal M(X)^*$ not in $\mathcal C(X)$.  A **more difficult** question would be: exhibit an infinite comapct $X$ where$ \big[\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \implies \mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu\big]$ is true.  Surely you should do that before you ask for conditions under which it is true.